# JUnit test case to check if file was created

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit3

I have created a simple program that wil create the dat file through buffered writer and will write some data into that file  , now please advise what junit test cases I can have through which  I can check whether the file is created or not in c: drive , I am using junit 3 , please advise.

Comment: Have you tried something? Maybe check if you can read that file.

Answer (score 41):

```
File file = new File("c:/pathOfTheCreatedFile");
assertTrue(file.exists());
// TODO: read the file. Check that it contains what it's supposed to contain
```