# Mockito check file exists

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to create JUnit test to check if file exists and get from context header and check length, content etc. 
I found this solutions: [JUnit test case to check if file was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397166/junit-test-case-to-check-if-file-was-created) but it's only for Unit Test. I use spring framework and I would like use Mockito to simulate created file. 
 Thank you.

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  Please [edit] your question to be far more specific about what help you need, so that this doesn't look like a "gimme teh codez" question.

Comment: Write a wrapper for the file system and use Mockito to mock the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make asserts on file in a unit test I would recommend you to use Temporary folder:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testCreateFile() throws IOException{
    File file = tempFolder.newFile("test.txt");
    assertTrue(file.exists());
}
```

You can find more information on Temporary folder [here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html).

Comment: Nice approach, the thing is that if you use a physical file, your test become an integration one, it is not a unit test anymore